Question about the Drude model
The question is very simple. Does the Drude model allow us to consider a space-varying electric field?
Since the relation is:
$$
m\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=-\frac{m}{\tau}\vec v + q_e\vec e
$$
I don't see a $$\frac{\partial \vec v}{\partial t}$$

You can always just turn the mathematical crank and see what you get; it should even be tolerable for slowly-varying-enough E fields. However, Drude model is just not good enough as-is, so why would you want to waste time on this? The textbooks will get you to much better descriptions of materials, and then you can deal with varying E fields in those better models.

because the Drude model is the starting point of the "derivation" of the first London equation for superconductors. And the first London equation consider spatially non uniform field.

Can you define terms of the equation?

Besides the fact that this model fails to predict some observed properties of solids, you can generalize it to space-varying electric fields. You can just write the velocity as the time derivative of the position $\vec{x}(t)$ of the charge and you get a 2nd order differential equation for $\vec{x}(t)$.
